# Compiling a c program on linux ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Hey guys please help me out here. I have made a c program. I'm new to it and compiling it and i'm getting an error thats making me pull my hair out.

error

as: unrecognized option "--32"

I've tried using gcc -c, gcc -o to no avail.

however, using gcc -S to get a asm file works.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've tried

```
gcc -c verilog.c
gcc -o verilog verilog.c
gcc -o verilog.c
gcc verilog.c -o verilog
```

I also got a warning on a part of my code but that wouldnt stop the compilation though right?

Comment: Try `gcc (code_file_name.c) -o (program_name_I_want)`.

Comment: Could you post the complete command you're using?

Comment: I've edited the post with the complete command

Comment: AtonH that also doesnt work either.

Comment: Assembler is not compatible or corrupted. Maybe should remove gcc and reinstall it

Comment: I just did a test with `gcc hellow.c -o hellow` and no problems. So like texasbruce says, problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: Those command lines wom't give such a error message, unless your system is broken beyond belief.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is your "gcc" command (which I suppose you're executing from a terminal) an alias? Maybe is has some option set up there that's causing problems.